# Ping inexistent IP

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machines, linux-networking, ping

I created an internal connection from my Debian VM to Metasploitable, i tried to ping Metasploitable's network address and it works, but when i tried to ping a random inexistent IP i was expecting the "destination host unreachable" error, which not occured. So i tried many random IPs and i pinged all of them normally, like they're existing, no differences from the Metasploitable's ping and the random IPs one. I think this is a problem because i'm not sure if the network is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check ARP table with `ip neigh  list`. The first 3 bytes of the MAC address are the ID of the manufacturer of the network card. You can search them here: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html

This will give you more insights about the IPs in your current VLAN.

Comment: Thank you for helping, i resolved that issue. My error was not changing the interface name from "eth0" to "enp0s3" in the interfaces file, i know that's so stupid lol.